# PHP Echoing a list

Tags: php, mysql

I have two sections to my coding, the first section will echo out dates between a start date and an end date (My possible dates). The second section echoes dates which are stored in a MYSQL database (Event dates). The issue I have now is when I try to echo the variable for possible dates and event dates. They echo the full list in there individual sections but in the last section it only echoes the last value in the list for both variables. I've tried making them global variables but still has the same outcome. The codes below:

```
 <?php
 //Section one//
$date1 = '10/06/2014';
$date2 = '30/06/2014';

function returnDates($fromdate, $todate) {
 $fromdate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fromdate);
    $todate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $todate);
    return new \DatePeriod(
    $fromdate,
    new \DateInterval('P1D'),
    $todate->modify('+1 day')
    );
}

$datePeriod = returnDates($date1, $date2);
foreach($datePeriod as $date) {
     $possible=($date->format('dmY'));
}
//section two - Event dates in the MYSQL database//


 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","apple","Orange1","cal");
  // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM events");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $dateday = $row['Day'];
  $datemonth = $row['Month'];
  $dateyear = $row['Year'];

  if($datemonth<"12"){
  $newmonthdate=("0$datemonth");
  }else{
  $newmonthdate=("$datemonth");
 }

   $taken=("$dateday$newmonthdate$dateyear");
}

// Section three - Removing 'event dates list' from 'possible dates list' //

echo "test"."<br>";
echo "$possible"."<br>";
echo "$taken"."<br>";



?>
```

Planning on removing the event dates stored in a MYSQL database from the possible dates to produce a new list, but was making sure the $possible and $taken represented the correct values in the last section but they don't.

What I currently get is:
test
30062014
17082014

Whereas I should get:
test
10062014

Comment: You're overwriting `$possible` on every iteration of `foreach`. Perhaps you meant `$possible[] = [...]`? From there, within your `while` loop, you could use `unset($possible[array_search($taken, $possible)])` to remove the item that exists in the DB.

Comment: I think you want `if($datemonth < 10){` as I don't think you want "011" as month... Also, when trying to determine algebraically if a number is less than another, you shouldn't use quotation marks.

Comment: Determination of a date being less than another date cannot be done with the format ddmmyyyy.  As 02062014 would be less than 01052014.  Much better to convert all dates to a time format (seconds since the epoch) via strtotime(...)  then a direct numeric comparison can be performed.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your variables $possible and $taken in the loops (foreach, while).

You could either use an array:

```
$possible=array(); # before foreach loop!
...
$possible[]=($date->format('dmY'));
```

or just add it all as a string (depends on your needs):

```
$possible=""; # before foreach loop!
...
$possible.= ($date->format('dmY'))."<br>";
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this out and see if I can get this to work.